# Unable to Get Text Input from Form

Tags: php, forms

For some reason I can't get the text input from the form. I'm successfully able to get the file.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="msform">
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">Upload Photo</h2>
  Select Image: <input type="file" name="image">
  Photo Name: <input type="text" name="photoName">
  Photo Name2: <input type="text" name="photoName">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" class="submit action-button">
</fieldset></form>
```

This is my code to get the form data:

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {

  // save file to Parse
  $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
  $file->save();

  $foo = $_POST['photoName'];
  echo $foo;
```

`$foo` does not display. I've tried using `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST`

Comment: have you tried to echo $foo before opening the file?

Comment: does your script reaches the echo statement?

Comment: @hakem I just tried calling $foo outside the if statement using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` It does not return the value

Comment: @moppo yes, I have additional statements past it that are printed

Comment: try a `var_dump($_POST);` at the beginning of the script to see the content

Comment: @Moppo this is the output `array(2) { ["photoName"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(12) "Upload Image" } ` though I am not familiar with what this means.

Comment: It appears that you are passing an empty string in the input photoname, are you writing a value in that input?

Comment: @Moppo But I believe my input is set correctly `<input type="text" name="photoName">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80300/discussion-between-moppo-and-emma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second input overrides the first. Try to make a:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

at the beginning of the php script, so you will see what is arriving as a parameter

Comment: I realized I had another input with the same name further down. Silly mistake but the `var_dump` was helpful. Thanks